# Internet Explorer hack for styling hover on non-link elements?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I have:

```
UL LI:hover {
    background-color: #729518;
}
```

which works fine on every browser except IE (<=9). I can only seem to style `:hover` on actual `a` tags with IE.

Does anyone know of a hack to get `:hover` working on other elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy reckons it only works if you have an HTML 4.01 strict DOCTYPE: http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762

For more complete hover support you may need to use a Javascript solution.

Comment: In IE, up to and including IE 10, `:hover` is supported for all elements in “Standards Mode” only. In “Quirks Mode”, many newer CSS constructs are ignored. But there are several doctype strings that set IE to “Standards Mode”. The simplest of them is `<!doctype html>` (to be placed at the very start of the document). If this does not help, there is probably something special that still puts IE to “Quirks Mode”, see http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/